# Item in RecyclerView not aligning as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

My app has a chat activity which contains a recyclerview. This recyclerview contains two items that display the messages received by the user and the messages sent by the user.

The messages received by the user is aligning from the left of the recyclerview as expected but the messages sent by the user is not aligning from the right of the recyclerview as expected.

This is how it looks right now:
The blue colored messages are the messages received and the gray colored messages are the messages sent.
[image: current ui of chat activity]

How I need the ui to look:
**I want the grey colored messages to align from the right of the screen like in the picture below.**
[image]

**CODE**

The activity.java file:

```
public class IMActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ImAdapter imAdapter;
    private List<ChatMsg> chatMsgList = new ArrayList<>();
    Socket mSocket;
    EditText etIM;
    ImageButton ibSend;
    String otherUserName;
    List<Msg> msgList;
    DBAct db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_im);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.imlist_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        etIM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_im);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_im);
        imAdapter = new ImAdapter(chatMsgList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imAdapter);

        db = new DBAct(IMActivity.this,otherUserName);
        msgList = db.getAllMessages();
        db.close();
        prepareChatData();
    }

    private void prepareChatData() {

        for (int i=0; i<msgList.size(); i++) {
            ChatMsg chatMsg = new ChatMsg(msgList.get(i).getMessage(),msgList.get(i).getOther());
            chatMsgList.add(chatMsg);
        }
        imAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The adapter class file:

```
public class ImAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ChatMsg> chatMsgList = new ArrayList<ChatMsg>();
    final int VIEW_TYPE_USER = 1;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_OTHER = 0;

    public ImAdapter(List<ChatMsg> chatMsgList){
        this.chatMsgList = chatMsgList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType==VIEW_TYPE_USER){
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_chat_msg_user,parent,false);
            return new ImUserViewHolder(itemView);
        }else {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_chat_msg_other,parent,false);
            return new ImOtherViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType()==VIEW_TYPE_USER){
            ChatMsg chatMsg = chatMsgList.get(position);
            ImUserViewHolder imUserViewHolder = (ImUserViewHolder)holder;
            imUserViewHolder.msg.setText(chatMsg.getMsg());
        }else {
            ChatMsg chatMsg = chatMsgList.get(position);
            ImOtherViewHolder imOtherViewHolder = (ImOtherViewHolder) holder;
            imOtherViewHolder.msg.setText(chatMsg.getMsg());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        ChatMsg chatMsg = chatMsgList.get(position);
        if (chatMsg.getOther().equals("true")){
            return VIEW_TYPE_OTHER;
        }else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_USER;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatMsgList.size();
    }

    public class ImOtherViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView msg;

        public ImOtherViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            msg = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_msg_other);
        }
    }

    public class ImUserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView msg;

        public ImUserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            msg = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_msg_user);
        }
    }
}
```

The activity layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_im"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.IMActivity"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/im_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/im_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/title">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8.7"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_im"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter message..."
                android:inputType="textPersonName">
            </EditText>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_cam_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="send"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The xml layout of the messages received (blue colored messages):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_im_chat_msg_other"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_chat_msg_other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is other"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_chat_msg_other"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_chat_msg_other"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_chat_msg_other"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_chat_msg_other"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml layout of the messages sent (gray colored messages):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_im_chat_msg_user"
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is me"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_im_chat_msg_user"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_chat_msg_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have set the relative layout's android:gravity="right" so that the gray message will be aligned to the right but apparently this isn't working. I even tried setting the android:layout_gravity="right" but the result is still the same.
Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for example wrap your `RelativeLayout` in the gray colored message layout in a `FrameLayout` and change `android:gravity="right"` to `android:layout_gravity="right"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_im_chat_msg_user"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_im_chat_msg_user"
            android:text="this is me"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_chat_msg_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_chat_msg_user"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textSize="11dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

You could also warp your `RelativeLayout` in another `RelativeLayout` and change from `android:gravit="right"` to `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`.